# How to take multiple inputs using readline module in js or node without for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, input

I am doing some java script practice so i want to take input from user

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
input: process.stdin,
output: process.stdout

});
```

now i want to take input as

```
rl.question('enter multiple inputs', function(arrayofinputs))
```

so how to take multiple inputs using

Comment: What is "multiple inputs" for the user? Is it space separated strings?

Comment: yes but every time it may change so no fix no of inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split(' ')` to get an array of strings out of the input that is separated by spaces.

```
rl.question('enter multiple inputs ', function(input) {
  var arrayOfInputs = input.trim().split(' ');
  console.log(arrayOfInputs);
  rl.close();
})
```

To handle multiple spaces between strings you should use RegExp:

```
rl.question('enter multiple inputs ', function(input) {
  var arrayOfInputs = input.trim().split(/\s+/);
  console.log(arrayOfInputs);
  rl.close();
})
```

`.trim()` is for removing spaces from the beginning and end of the input.